# In c# winforms, how to get the event that activated a window and forward it

Tags: c#, winforms

Let me first explain my current situation and why I think I need this. It may very well be the case that I am handling this completely the wrong way and am thus open to suggestions.

We have a c# program which uses winforms and only has an embededded System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser which shows a website with an embedded java applet.
Our users have several of these programs opened at a time. The java applet sometimes needs some time to calculate data and the user meanwhile just uses one of his other windows. When the java applet finishes it sets focus to itself and the whole window pops on top which interrupts the other task the user was doing. We don't have access to the java applets source and can't modify it in any way. Calling a java script function which was hooked up through COM to the WebBrowser has the same effect btw.

To counter this we created the event "Deactivate" on the whole form. When called it sets the embedded WebBrowser.Enabled = false. In the corresponding event "Activated" the WebBrowser gets enabled again.
This works really nice: windows don't pop on top anymore just because the java applet wants to set the focus to itself while in the background.

The problem we now have is that when a user clicks on a deactivated window the window gets activated but the mouse click doesn't get forwarded to the WebBrowser. So for example a user has to click twice to press a button.

So I think my question is how to forward the mouse click which activated the window to the WebBrowser.

Thanks in advance
Markus

Comment: When I'm getting you right, you could call `WebBrowser.Select()`in the `Form_Activated` event:    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sounds tricky. maybe it is easier to suppress the window message from java that is causing the window to focus, by a WndProc override in the form that hosts the Webbrowser. (@RomCoo they try to forward the actual click event, not just the activation. like when you open two browsers next to each other, you can open a link in the one that is in the background, with just one click)

Comment: @dlatikay Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried it out, overrode WndProc for the whole window and looked at the messages it gets which are always in this order WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED. After that I get several diffent messages which always come in a different order: WM_ACTIVATEAPP WM_GETICON, WM_NCACTIVE, WM_ACTIVATE. I think this is pretty inconclusive since I would need to know the source of these messages :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. It works but I don't like it:

```
    [DllImport( "user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
    public static extern void mouse_event( uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo );

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;

    protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
    {
        // If the panel which contains the WebBrowser was diabled, the messages WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_RBUTTONDOWN will not reach the panel
        // but will reach the window instead. We then resend them.
        if( m.Msg == 0x0201 ) // WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        {
            short x, y;
            MouseCoordsFromMessage( m, out x, out y );

            mouse_event( MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, (uint)x, (uint)y, 0, 0 );
        }
        else if( m.Msg == 0x0204 ) // WM_RBUTTONDOWN
        {
            short x, y;
            MouseCoordsFromMessage( m, out x, out y );

            mouse_event( MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, (uint)x, (uint)y, 0, 0 );
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc( ref m );
        }
    }

    private static void MouseCoordsFromMessage( Message m, out short x, out short y )
    {
        x = unchecked( (short)(long)m.LParam );
        y = unchecked( (short)( (long)m.LParam >> 16 ) );
    }
```

I am not sure how fragile this is and would like to hear other opinions.